# How to detect AVB is running normally or not android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kernel, android-source, boot

AVB is Android Verified Boot.

How to detect in case an abnormality is detected while executing AVB?

From boot, I need to notify whether it started normally or not.

Is it possible to check through application? Where exactly to detect if it runs abnormality or normal?

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

you can check the property "ro.boot.veritymode" which value can be "enforcing" or "disabled".

Comment: Also "logging".